# AJAX call not working even on this simple form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Currently i have this code to test, because ajax calls for some reason i can't make it work, can anyone check what can be wrong?

test.php

```
<html>
<body>
 <form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname">
<input type="submit" id="data-send-button" value="Send Data">
</form>

<div id="responce-box"> </div>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "submit.php",
            data : $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend : function() {
                alert("indo");
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
 </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
echo "test";
```

That is just for testing.
Thanks guys!

Comment: As you are using AJAX for data submit you don't need to put `type="submit"` instead you have to use `type="button"` also after that please follow @guradio's comment

Comment: change this `$("#myform").submit` to `$("#data-send-button").click` also remove the second `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @RanaGhosh really ?

Comment: `can anyone check what can be wrong` check your console log your self and see

Comment: I guess it worked but just didn't show the result. wheres a function for handle the result when call was successful?

Comment: @guradio Nothing happens when i click the button!

Comment: $.ajax({...
beforeSend:...,
success: function(result){
        ...}
});

Comment: @codhxh12 because you didnt include the jquery script please check console for error

Comment: @codhxh12 try my solution check it is working or not. Simply just need to add jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example I think you don't have include jquery

try this:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname">
<input type="submit" id="data-send-button" value="Send Data">
</form>

<div id="responce-box"> </div>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "submit.php",
            data : $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend : function() {
                alert("indo");
            }

        });

    });

});
 </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks all this worked! But now how i can read the form inputs on the other file?

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine but you need to include jquery library if you use jquery tag. so add this library and check your code it will be working
and tested

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="text" id="fname">
        <input type="text" id="lname">
        <input type="submit" id="data-send-button" value="Send Data">
    </form>

    <div id="responce-box"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "submit.php",
                    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        alert("indo");
                    }

                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

for more example

https://jquery.com/

Comment: This is bad way to explain the answer.